# In need of help regarding a down-voted accepted answer

Tags: discussion, answers, downvotes, accepted-answer

Before I ask my question, I would just like to say that I know that similar questions have been asked here before, but none of them can give me an answer regarding my specific situation.

I answered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42583751/how-can-i-add-dynamic-list-with-unique-id-to-a-ordered-list) relatively simple html/javascript question last night after seeing that the provided answer didn't work(until it was later edited.. and then deleted).

After posting I received a few down-votes in a relatively short amount of time, which I don't mind at all, but I would at least like a reason - as the whole reason I joined SO is to learn and improve.

So my question to you is: Are the down-votes on my answer deserved, and if they are - what can I do to make my future answers more useful?

Comment: Many people think that off-topic questions should not be answered at all. That might b your problem.

Comment: I see, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: The issue is the main page gets cluttered with these type of general off topic questions which are not useful to the site. answering them would encourage the behavior. So people downvote even the answers. For the record I havent downvoted it..

Comment: I understand - Im still new to the site so I just answered the question without taking that into account and since my answer is the accepted one there isn't much I can do now apart from edit it. I'll keep it in mind for future reference though. Thanks for taking the time to explain everything